# Number of items in a document library conflicting

Tags: 2013, 2010, document-library, list-item

We have a document library in SP2010 that we are trying to migrate to SP2013 using a 3rd party tool. The issue is that in destination after migration the number of items shown for this library is 7980 but the source shows 8003. The migration report also does not show any error. Also when we collected a report using powershell for the source library it says 7980 items. If thats the case why is it showing 8003 items on the web page in our 2010 site -

```
<site>/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be it is considering the folders as a count. Check How many folders you have and create a view to have items without folder.

Answer (score 0):

On the source library, you can see if it contains any files that haven't been checked in by navigating to the **Library Settings** page, then clicking "**Manage files which have no checked in version**."

Those files are only visible to the person(s) who uploaded them. If you want to bring them along to the destination library, you can take ownership of them and then check them in before running the migration.